# Array Fill w/Grouping

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

This is one of those, " I wish I had listened better, retained more of my math class info..", questions. I did this with brute force, but I know there's a better more correct way of accomplishing this.

Given a 4 x 4 array of stations, and 8 groups(a-h). How to fill the array with group pair combinations so each pair(ab, ba) occurs only once, and each group occurs only once in each row and column? (If a is part of a pair in 1,1, it can no long appear in a grouping in row 1 or column 1)

Of course not all possible groupings happen.

Comment: You've got 42 group pairs 42 combinations: how can that fit into the 16 (4 x 4) array stations?

Comment: Are the pairs (ab) and (ba) considered the same?

Comment: ab and ba are considered the same group. Not all groupings have to occur, but no duplicates(the before mentioned ab or ba), are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think brute force is the way to go, though you can invest into trimming branches smarter if you wish.

Comment: Brute force did get the job done, now it's an intellectual exercise, chance to learn something.

Comment: Sure, but I'm certainly better at math than median programmer and I still don't see any significant optimizations. But if you had 4 groups, I think there's a theory about "Magic Squares".

Comment: After more checking your're correct, the answer is brute force...thanks